# Using has class to show/hide rows results in lag and performance hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a quite large HTML table that I am showing/hiding rows based on their class. The code works as desired, but there is around a 10 second lag/freeze of the client. Please note amount of departments in my example could be dynamic, hence some of the reasoning of the crazy table structure.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/qxdwrq7x/8/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#deptOpt").on('change', function() {
    var dept = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    $("#scLDP > tbody > tr").each(function() {
      var x = $(this);
      switch (dept) {
        case 0:
          $("#scLDP > tbody > tr").show();
          break;
        default:
          $("#scLDP > tbody > tr").hide();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHand.dept" + dept).prev().prev().show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHand.dept" + dept).prev().show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHand.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHandQ.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .poss.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .posq.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .wos.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .stP.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .twmd.dept" + dept).show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .grandT").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHandGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .onHandQGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .possGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .posqGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .wosGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .stpGrand").show();
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .twmdGrand").show();
          break;
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: When updating huge chunks of HTML try not to write to the DOM with each single update as that causes lag. Make the changes in memory, then replace the whole chunk of the DOM in a single update. there is several ways of doing so, i.e: detaching the relevant HTML, updating it and re-attaching it, cloning the relevant HTML, updating the clone and then replacing the relevant HTML in the DOM, etc..

Comment: that is because your event handler is written a  massive loop.  Why in heck would you set those classes repeatedly (for every tr) in a massive table?

Comment: Those classes all exist because this table is for the most part dynamically generated along with a lot of mathematical calculations that generate some of the rows even

Comment: you don't even refer to the current row (`x`) in the `.each` loop

Comment: @sm1l3y: Do you need the loop? Sorry if I missed something but does that not do the same? https://jsfiddle.net/zgpgzrc2/ I seem to be getting the same results in your code as in mine, not using the loop. If the loop isn't needed you don't need to clone the table as I have done either.

Comment: good catch, I meant to set var x as the current row for cacheing..

Comment: Francois...perfect thank you

Comment: @sm1l3y you should still consider cleaning up your HTML structure considerably.  Your code is a lot harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you don't need the `.each` as the selectors should find everything.

When removing it your code is fast and seems to give the same results.

```
var dept = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    //$("#scLDP > tbody > tr").each(function() {
      var x = $(this);
      switch (dept) {
       ....
       ....
          $("#scLDP > tbody > .twmdGrand").show();
          break;
      }
    //})
  })
})
```

See Fiddle without the `each` loop ► https://jsfiddle.net/dL7zhvfq/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure simply needs one extra class value on *every* `<tr>` element that indicates which department it belongs too, with another for the grand total rows.

Nor does it need the `.each` loop - you're not iterating over the rows yourself so it's pointless.

Your code would then become far simpler and easier to maintain:

```
$("#deptOpt").on('change', function() {
    var dept = this.selectedIndex;
    if (dept === 0) {
        $('#scLDP tr').show();
    } else {
        $('#scLDP tr').hide();
        $('#scLDP tr.dept' + dept).show();
        $('#scLDP tr.total').show();
    }
});
```

Note that adding `.deptN` to the individual `<tr>` elements means you don't need it on the `<td>` elements any more either.

An alternative would be to have a separate `<tbody>` for each department, each with its own class.